# AJAX form not returning data when using input file

Tags: ajax, file, upload, response

im experiencing a weird issue. I have this form basically it just sends data to another cfm file that processes the inputs and updates a database. Today ive added an input type="file" so to process EXIF data from it and extract GPS info. The result page will copy a div to the specified target div. All works fine, data gets extracted and updated, but the div with the response does not appear anymore. As soon as i remove the input="file" div target div gets updated. Seems a response header issue, but i have no idea how to fix it. Thanks.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind form using ajaxForm 
        $('#sede-form').ajaxForm({ 
            // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response 
            target: '#htmlExampleTarget', 
            // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response 
            // has been received; here we apply a fade-in effect to the new content 
            success: function() { 
                $('#htmlExampleTarget').fadeIn('slow'); 
            } 
        }); 
    });
</script> 
<cfoutput query="dett_cli">                 
    <form id="sede-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="modifica_sede_response.cfm" method="post" class="form-inline">
        <input type="hidden" name="codice" value="#url.codice#" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id_sede" value="#url.id_sede#" />
        ... [other fields]...
        <input type="hidden" name="sed_coordinate_o" value="#sed_coordinate#" class="input-large">  
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="sed_coordinate">JPG Coordinate GPS </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <input type="file" name="sed_coordinate" id="sed_coordinate" class="input-large">   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ... [other fields]...
        <!-- END div.row-fluid -->
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-repeat"></i> Resetta</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Aggiorna</button>
            <div  id="htmlExampleTarget"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following back into your ajaxForm options.

```
iframe:true,
forceSync:true,
```